# How to retrieve elements from youtube data api

Tags: xml, vb.net, youtube-api, gdata

This is what i doing but i get 400 bad request error

```
  Dim request = String.Format("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={0}&orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2&fields=title,media:group/yt:duration,media:group/media:thumbnail", searchItem)

  Dim responseByte() As Byte = New WebClient().DownloadData(request)
  Dim responseXML As String = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte)
```

Comment: That URL doesn't work in a browser either.  It works ok up through `fields=title`, but, once you include the stuff after that, it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

GData is going to be deprecated. I'd suggest using [Data API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Here's a great example to start. There are more in the folder to exploit.

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/Search.cs